# How can I color code output from ITestOutputHelper.WriteLine

Tags: c#, xunit

To ease debugging I'm writing out some information when a unit test fails. This comes out as white text and is hard to read. I'd like to color code this, is it possible?

https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output

```
    public TestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _log = output;
    }
    [Fact]
    public void RequiredAttributeTest()
    {
        ....setup code
        foreach(var error in results)
            {                        
                _log.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
             }
         }
         Assert.Equal(false, isValid);
     }
```

Comment: _"This comes out as white text and is hard to read."_ **where** are you seeing white text? xUnit's log output is shown in VS's Test Explorer window - so if text is shown as white-on-white there then that's a bug in Test Explorer, not xUnit nor your code.

Comment: I'm using VS code and the command line "dotnet test.." to run my tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it, but after reading a few of xUnit's sources, I'd say it is not possible.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/783) and [this piece of code](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/common/ConsoleHelper.cs), ANSI color support should work when running your xUnit test suite on Linux.

But `ConsoleHelper.SetForegroundColor` is `internal` and will be set by `DiagnosticMessageSink` - an object you can retrieve via xUnit's output functionality ([see here](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output#output-in-extensions)), but the console color cannot be set `public`ly ([see here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/v2/src/xunit.console/Sinks/DiagnosticMessageSink.cs#L38-L39)).

Maybe you can ask Brad Wilson, the maintainer of xUnit, if he has further ideas of plans to support this feature.